# Intel 8080: Memory offset calculation

Tags: assembly, emulation, bit-manipulation, intel-8080

I am reading this guide about Intel 8080 emulation [Emulator 101](http://www.emulator101.com/) and when I'm reading the code to check what I wrote, I stumbled upon this

```
case 0x36:      //MVI   M,byte
{                   
//AC set if lower nibble of h was zero prior to dec
uint16_t offset = (state->h<<8) | state->l;
state->memory[offset] = opcode[1];
state->pc++;
}
break;
```

from a book called Intel 8080/8085 Assembly Language Programming, I read about MVI this

> This instruction copies the data stored in its second byte into the
>   memory location addressed by H and L. M is a symbolic reference to the
>   H and L register pair.

so I'm guessing that the offset is the memory location addressed by H and L, but why do we do it that way? That is `(state->h<<8) | state->l`

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "why do we do it that way"? The documentation says `M` is a convention for the `H` and `L` pair, and the `H` and `L` registers are combined (via `<<` and `|`) to provide the 16-bit offset. What do you want to know again?

Comment: what I meant is how is the combination of `<<` and `|` gives us the 16-bit offset?

Comment: Representing a 16 bit value requires two bytes. Left shift over 8 bits puts the value of `h` in the second (*h* igh) byte (and a 0 into the low byte), and `|` combines it with the *l* ow byte (value of `l`), producing the needed offset. Look into little-endianness and bitwise operations.

Comment: Thanks DCoder very much, that helped me alot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how is the combination of << and | gives us the 16-bit offset?

Take `H`, an 8-bit register, where H<sub>7</sub> is the most significant bit and H<sub>0</sub> is the least significant bit:

```
H7H6H5H4H3H2H1H0
```

Take `L`, an 8-bit register, where L<sub>7</sub> is the most significant bit and L<sub>0</sub> is the least significant bit:

```
L7L6L5L4L3L2L1L0
```

You now want to construct the 16-bit offset that results from combining `H` (**H**ighest 8-bits) and `L` (**L**owest 8-bits.)  In C/C++/Java this can be achieved by an 8-bit shift-left `<<` followed by a bitwise-or `|` as follows:

```
H      =                 H7H6H5H4H3H2H1H0
H<<8   = H7H6H5H4H3H2H1H00 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
H<<8|L = H7H6H5H4H3H2H1H0L7L6L5L4L3L2L1L0
```